# Fast way to count the numbers that are divisible by their own sum of digits inside a range

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372178/how-to-count-the-numbers-that-are-divisible-by-their-sum-of-digits) on Stack Overflow, I wrote a function that returns the length of a list made of numbers that are divisible by their own sum of digits inside a range:

```
-- Returns the digits of a positive integer as a list, in reverse order.
-- This is slightly more efficient than in forward order.
digitsRev :: Int -> [Int]
digitsRev i = case i of
    0 -> []
    _ -> lastDigit : digitsRev rest
where (rest, lastDigit) = quotRem i 10

-- Returns the digits of a positive integer as a list.
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits = reverse . digitsRev

-- Returns the sum of digits of a positive integer
sumDigits :: Int -> Int
sumDigits = sum . digits

-- Returns True if a number is divisible by the sum of it's digits and False
-- otherwise.
isDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Bool
isDivisibleSumDigits n = n `mod` sumDigits n == 0

-- Returns a range of positive integers in which every element is divisible by 
-- the sum of it's digits. Includes the end of the range.
rangeDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
rangeDivisibleSumDigits range_start range_end =
    [n | n <- [range_start..range_end], isDivisibleSumDigits n == True]

-- Returns the length of the list returned by rangeDivisibleSumDigits
lengthRangeDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Int -> Int
lengthRangeDivisibleSumDigits range_start range_end = 
    length $ rangeDivisibleSumDigits range_start range_end
```

Then I used this function inside a main function, like this:

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ lengthRangeDivisibleSumDigits 1 10000000
```

According to the file generated by profiling the program (compiling like this: `ghc -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts Main.hs` and executing like this: `./Main +RTS -p`) it took 14.36 seconds to execute `main`. That's slow.

Do you have ideas on a faster way to perform the task carried out by this function?

### Edit

Thanks to @bisserlis 's answer below, now the code reads:

```
-- Returns the digits of a positive integer as a list.
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits = map digitToInt . show

-- Returns True if a number is divisible by the sum of it's digits and False
-- otherwise
isDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Bool
isDivisibleSumDigits n = n `mod` (sum (digits n)) == 0

-- Returns a range of positive integers in which every element is divisible by 
-- the sum of it's digits. Includes the end of the range.
rangeDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
rangeDivisibleSumDigits start end = filter isDivisibleSumDigits [start..end]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile without profiling, but with optimizations turned on.

```
bissbook:divSumDigits bisserlis$ ghc -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts original.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( original.hs, original.o )
Linking original ...
bissbook:divSumDigits bisserlis$ ./original +RTS -s
806095
  44,577,697,768 bytes allocated in the heap
      81,431,504 bytes copied during GC
          62,504 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          23,392 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     85945 colls,     0 par    0.48s    0.57s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time   22.36s  ( 22.79s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.48s  (  0.57s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   22.85s  ( 23.35s elapsed)

  %GC     time       2.1%  (2.4% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,993,498,737 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  97.9% of total user, 95.8% of total elapsed

bissbook:divSumDigits bisserlis$ rm *.hi *.o
bissbook:divSumDigits bisserlis$ ghc -O2 original.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( original.hs, original.o )
Linking original ...
bissbook:divSumDigits bisserlis$ ./original +RTS -s
806095
  12,176,087,768 bytes allocated in the heap
       4,273,680 bytes copied during GC
          44,416 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          21,120 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     23449 colls,     0 par    0.09s    0.11s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    2.87s  (  2.93s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.09s  (  0.11s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    2.96s  (  3.04s elapsed)

  %GC     time       3.0%  (3.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,237,427,802 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  97.0% of total user, 94.6% of total elapsed
```

(Note the `Total   time` lines, 22.85s and 2.96s.)

---

I can't appreciably increase the performance any further, but I do have a couple stylistic notes.

`Data.Char` provides a function `digitToInt :: Char -> Int`, which makes writing `digits` much easier.

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits = map digitToInt . show
```

No need to use list comprehensions and boolean double-checking in `rangeDivisibleSumDigits`, just write it as a filter on the range.

```
rangeDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
rangeDivisibleSumDigits start end = filter isDivisibleSumDigits [start..end]
```

`sumDigits` and `lengthRangeDivisibleSumDigits` are unnecessary functions, their names are pretty much as long as their implementations! They clutter up the top-level, they don't do anything surprising or interesting, I'd just use their implementations wherever you need to instead of adding another function to your mental burden.

Comment: Stylistic notes are always appreciated. Do you have any ideas on the algorithms part?

Comment: Actually this would be a perfect problem for parallelization, which should give you a linear speedup in the number of processors. I'd have to pull down my copy of *Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell* for a refresher before taking a stab at it though.

Answer (score 1):

Little addition to bisserlis answer.

It's not necessarily convert a number to a string (or list) to evaluate sum of digits, so try to rewrite your new code as:

```
-- Returns the sum of digits of a positive integer
sumDigits :: Int -> Int
sumDigits n = let (rest,lastDigit) = quotRem n 10 in if n == 0 then 0 else lastDigit + sumDigits rest

-- Returns True if a number is divisible by the sum of it's digits and False
-- otherwise
isDivisibleSumDigits :: Int -> Bool
isDivisibleSumDigits n = n `rem` (sumDigits n) == 0
```

Comment: Your code didn't work as it was written. I've modified it slightly to this `sumDigits :: Int -> Int
sumDigits n = if n == 0 then 0 else
    lastDigit + sumDigits rest where (lastDigit, rest) = quotRem n 10`, but my system started to slow down when I ran it, so I stopped the execution.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, my code has mistake due to my experiments with it. True line is `sumDigits n = let (rest,lastDigit) = quotRem n 10 in if n == 0 then 0 else lastDigit + sumDigits rest`. Your modification is also right.